# How to write a custom code inspector for GoLand to highlight initialization of struct fields with zero values?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

I love how GoLand can autocomplete the initialization of a struct with all fields and their zero values, however leaving said zero values in the struct initialization is not considered idiomatic and adds noise to the code. I'd like a code inspector to highlight these lines as a reminder to either set a different value, or remove them. I've read the very limited docs about writing custom code inspectors, but they really weren't helpful.